# Using table upon a subset gets frequencies for the whole DF not the subset

Tags: r

I am using a subset to extract from set of a column values

I have a DF with several columns, one of them is state. I need to get frequencies for state but just for some set of states. So I have this:

```
tmp <- subset(DF, DF$STATE %in% SOMESTATES)
a   <- as.data.frame(table(tmp$STATE))
```

This is almost fine. The tmp data frame has only the records belonging to the SOMESTATES set, fine.

The issue is a. The table result is the complete frequencies for the whole DF, not the tmp only. The other has zero values.

My problem here is some states in SOMESTATES has zero appearances in the DF, which this prevents me to use droplevels. droplevels  takes out also those zero values. Here as well:

If I use droplevels like this, for example, I loose the zero values for some states that I need.

```
tmp <- subset(DF, DF$STATE %in% SOMESTATES)
tmp2 <- droplevels(tmp)
table(tmp2$STATE)
```

presents all the states not only the ones in SOMESTATES

Any advise is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
tmp <- subset(DF, DF$STATE %in% SOMESTATES) 
tmp$STATE <- factor(tmp$STATE, levels=SOMESTATES) 
table(tmp$STATE)
```

The factor function will recreate it into a new factor whose levels match `SOMESTATES` exactly.  Those states who are not in `SOMESTATES` will not be included as they are neither in the data nor `SOMESTATES`, but those states with 0 count that are in `SOMESTATES` will still be included in the factor, and hence the table with 0 counts.

Note also that the factor levels will be ordered by `SOMESTATES` so the order in that vector will be the order that shows up in the tables or plots using it.  Generally this is benign or useful.

Comment: If maintaining the order of the factor levels as they were before sub-setting really matters, replace `levels=SOMESTATES` with `levels=levels(DF$STATE)[levels(DF$STATE) %in% SOMESTATES]`

Comment: Greg: Thanks, this did it.  By any chance any information about the why of this? I mean. Why the table "revives" the old information.

Brian: I need the result in order, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: The factor function without the levels argument guesses at the factor levels based on the data, but here you specify exactly what factor levels you want it to have and it will include those levels even if there is no data for them, hence the 0 counts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `table(factor(tmp$STATE))` or `table(tmp$STATE[, drop=T])`. Both will also retain original level ordering.